# Enabling security in a cluster with two nodes in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm trying to enable security feature in Elasticsearch nodes but whenever I turn on "xpack.security.enabled: true" , my Elasticsearch won't start at all. How can I resolve this?

here's my configuration on both of Elasticsearch nodes:
Node 1:

> ```
> # ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
> #
> # NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
> #       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
> #       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
> #
> # The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
> # the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
> #
> # Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
> # https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
> #
> # ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
> #
> # Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
> #
> cluster.name: "elastic-a"
> #
> # ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
> #
> # Use a descriptive name for the node:
> #
> node.name: "elastic-master"
> node.master: true
> node.data: true
> #
> # Add custom attributes to the node:
> #
> #node.attr.rack: r1
> #
> # ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
> #
> # Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
> #
> path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
> #
> # Path to log files:
> #
> path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
> #
> # ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
> #
> # Lock the memory on startup:
> #
> #bootstrap.memory_lock: true
> #
> # Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
> # on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
> # limit.
> #
> # Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
> #
> # ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
> #
> # Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
> #
> network.host: 192.168.143.30
> #http.host: 0.0.0.0
> #
> # Set a custom port for HTTP:
> #
> #http.port: 9200
> #
> # For more information, consult the network module documentation.
> #
> # --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
> #
> # Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
> # The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
> #
> discovery.seed_hosts: ["192.168.143.30", "192.168.143.23"]
> #
> # Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
> #
> cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["elastic-master","elastic-slave"]
> #
> # For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
> #
> # ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
> #
> # Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
> #
> #gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
> #
> # For more information, consult the gateway module documentation.
> #
> # ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
> #
> # Require explicit names when deleting indices:
> #
> #action.destructive_requires_name: true
> action.auto_create_index: .monitoring*,.watches,.triggered_watches,.watcher-history*,.ml*
> xpack.security.enabled: true
> ```

Node 2:

> ```
> # ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
> #
> # NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
> #       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
> #       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
> #
> # The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
> # the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
> #
> # Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
> # https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
> #
> # ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
> #
> # Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
> #
> cluster.name: "elastic-a"
> #
> # ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
> #
> # Use a descriptive name for the node:
> #
> node.name: "elastic-slave"
> node.master: true
> node.data: true
> #
> # Add custom attributes to the node:
> #
> #node.attr.rack: r1
> #
> # ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
> #
> # Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
> #
> path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
> #
> # Path to log files:
> #
> path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
> #
> # ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
> #
> # Lock the memory on startup:
> #
> #bootstrap.memory_lock: true
> #
> # Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
> # on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
> # limit.
> #
> # Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
> #
> # ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
> #
> # Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
> #
> network.host: 192.168.143.23
> #http.host: 0.0.0.0
> #
> # Set a custom port for HTTP:
> #
> #http.port: 9200
> #
> # For more information, consult the network module documentation.
> #
> # --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
> #
> # Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
> # The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
> #
> discovery.seed_hosts: ["192.168.143.30", "192.168.143.23"]
> #
> # Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
> #
> cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["elastic-master","elastic-slave"]
> #
> # For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
> #
> # ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
> #
> # Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
> #
> #gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
> #
> # For more information, consult the gateway module documentation.
> #
> # ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
> #
> # Require explicit names when deleting indices:
> #
> #action.destructive_requires_name: true
> action.auto_create_index: .monitoring*,.watches,.triggered_watches,.watcher-history*,.ml*
> xpack.security.enabled: true
> ```

I can enable security feature without setting up nodes (single node) but It doesn't work after setting up nodes.

sudo journalctl -f logs:

```
Oct 21 12:24:51 elastic-master systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
Oct 21 12:24:52 elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Oct 21 12:24:53 elastic-master kibana[781]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-10-21T08:54:53Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":781,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://192.168.143.30:9200/"}
Oct 21 12:24:53 elastic-master kibana[781]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-10-21T08:54:53Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":781,"message":"No living connections"}
Oct 21 12:24:53 elastic-master kibana[781]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-10-21T08:54:53Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":781,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://192.168.143.30:9200/"}
Oct 21 12:24:53 elastic-master kibana[781]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-10-21T08:54:53Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":781,"message":"No living connections"}
Oct 21 12:24:53 elastic-master kibana[781]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-10-21T08:54:53Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":781,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://192.168.143.30:9200/"}
Oct 21 12:24:53 elastic-master kibana[781]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-10-21T08:54:53Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":781,"message":"No living connections"}
Oct 21 12:24:53 elastic-master kibana[781]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-10-21T08:54:53Z","tags":["warning","plugins","licensing"],"pid":781,"message":"License information could not be obtained from Elasticsearch for the [data] cluster. Error: No Living connections"}
Oct 21 12:24:54 elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: [2020-10-21T12:24:54,557][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [elastic-master] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (rootfs)]], net usable_space [32.3gb], net total_space [43.9gb], types [rootfs]
Oct 21 12:24:54 elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: [2020-10-21T12:24:54,561][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [elastic-master] heap size [989.8mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
Oct 21 12:24:54 elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: [2020-10-21T12:24:54,612][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [elastic-master] node name [elastic-master], node ID [1lAXp_eJRL--r0o2Uq4P1Q], cluster name [elastic-a]
Oct 21 12:24:54 elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: [2020-10-21T12:24:54,613][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [elastic-master] version[7.5.0], pid[18296], build[default/rpm/e9ccaed468e2fac2275a3761849cbee64b39519f/2019-11-26T01:06:52.518245Z], OS[Linux/3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64/amd64], JVM[AdoptOpenJDK/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/13.0.1/13.0.1+9]
Oct 21 12:24:54 elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: [2020-10-21T12:24:54,613][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [elastic-master] JVM home [/usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk]
Oct 21 12:24:54 elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: [2020-10-21T12:24:54,613][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [elastic-master] JVM arguments [-Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT, -Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch-1946051170077590643, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/lib/elasticsearch, -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/elasticsearch/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=536870912, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=rpm, -Des.bundled_jdk=true]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: [2020-10-21T12:24:55,042][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [elastic-master] uncaught exception in thread [main]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to load plugin class [org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.XPackPlugin]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:163) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:150) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:125) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:115) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to load plugin class [org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.XPackPlugin]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:614) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundle(PluginsService.java:556) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundles(PluginsService.java:471) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:163) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:309) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:253) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:221) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:221) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:349) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: ... 6 more
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:605) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundle(PluginsService.java:556) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundles(PluginsService.java:471) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:163) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:309) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:253) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:221) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:221) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:349) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: ... 6 more
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSecurityException: failed to load SSL configuration [xpack.security.transport.ssl]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.loadConfiguration(SSLService.java:449) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.loadSSLConfigurations(SSLService.java:430) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.<init>(SSLService.java:121) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.XPackPlugin.<init>(XPackPlugin.java:142) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:605) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundle(PluginsService.java:556) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundles(PluginsService.java:471) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:163) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:309) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:253) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:221) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:221) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:349) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: ... 6 more
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to initialize SSL TrustManager - not permitted to read truststore file [/etc/elasticsearch/certs/elastic-certificates.p12]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.TrustConfig.unreadableTrustConfigFile(TrustConfig.java:121) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.StoreTrustConfig.createTrustManager(StoreTrustConfig.java:70) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.createSslContext(SSLService.java:384) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1138) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.loadConfiguration(SSLService.java:446) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.loadSSLConfigurations(SSLService.java:430) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.<init>(SSLService.java:121) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.XPackPlugin.<init>(XPackPlugin.java:142) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:605) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundle(PluginsService.java:556) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundles(PluginsService.java:471) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:163) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:309) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:253) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:221) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:221) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:349) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: ... 6 more
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /etc/elasticsearch/certs/elastic-certificates.p12
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:219) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:374) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:425) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:420) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:159) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.TrustConfig.getStore(TrustConfig.java:95) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.StoreTrustConfig.createTrustManager(StoreTrustConfig.java:65) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.createSslContext(SSLService.java:384) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1138) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.loadConfiguration(SSLService.java:446) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.loadSSLConfigurations(SSLService.java:430) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.<init>(SSLService.java:121) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.XPackPlugin.<init>(XPackPlugin.java:142) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[?:?]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:605) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundle(PluginsService.java:556) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundles(PluginsService.java:471) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:163) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:309) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:253) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:221) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:221) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:349) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0]
   elastic-master elasticsearch[18296]: ... 6 more
   elastic-master systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
   elastic-master systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
   elastic-master systemd[1]: Unit elasticsearch.service entered failed state.
   elastic-master systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service failed.
   elastic-master polkitd[814]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:18290:7813320 (system bus name :1.429, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you turn on security, it is mandatory that the nodes talk to each other via SSL, i.e. you need to configure your nodes to [encrypt communications between them](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/configuring-tls.html#configuring-tls). So you need to perform a few steps:

**Step 1: [Generate a node certificate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/configuring-tls.html#node-certificates)**

In this step, there are two options:

**A.** If you don't have any root certificate authority to sign your certificate, you can create one using `bin/elasticsearch-certutil ca` (follow the steps explained [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/configuring-tls.html#node-certificates)). You'll obtain a certificate encoded in PKCS#12 that contains the root CA certificate, the node certificate and the private key.

**B.** If your organization has a root certificate authority (Digicert, etc), you can [create a CSR](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/certutil.html#certutil-csr) (certificate signing request) to submit to your root CA. Usually, you'll obtain a certificate encoded in PKCS#7. PS: Let us know if this is the path you're taking because there are a few more steps involved to transform that to PKCS#12.

Note that for testing purposes you can definitely use the same certificate on both nodes, i.e. you don't need to generate one certificate per node.

**Step 2: [Modify your configuration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/configuring-tls.html#tls-transport)**

Once you have your node certificate (either through option A or B), you can modify the configuration on both nodes by adding the following in your `elasticsearch.yml` files:

```
# enable security
xpack.security.enabled: true

# make sure the nodes talk in SSL to each other
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: certs/mynode.p12 
xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path: certs/mynode.p12
```

After that you can restart your cluster as they can now talk in SSL to each other.

Comment: Thanks Val, I've followed your instruction but my ES fails to start.

Comment: I just added my ES log at end of my question.

Comment: Which version of ES are you using? the `oss` one or the `basic`? If the former, that one doesn't have the security plugin bundled.

Comment: It's ES 7.5.0 Basic

Comment: Can you also share what's in the journal? `sudo journalctl -f`? See here how to set it up: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/rpm.html#rpm-running-systemd

Comment: That error usually arises when a certificate is missing. Make sure that all the paths to the certificates are correct and accessible in the config file

Comment: I've updated my question with "sudo journalctl -f" log.

Comment: What I would like it the content of the journal when you start ES, because now we're just seeing Kibana complaining that it can't find ES.

Comment: You're right, rechecked it while my ES was running and updated with ES log.

Comment: Nice, so that's exactly the problem I was mentioning: `AccessDeniedException: /etc/elasticsearch/elastic-certificates.p12` Are you sure that the file is there and has the proper rights? Note that you need to store it here instead `/etc/elasticsearch/config/certs/elastic-certificates.p12`, i.e. create the `certs` folder in the same folder as you have your `elasticsearch.yml` file

Comment: Thanks Val, I've changed files path to "/etc/elasticsearch/certs" but I still get "java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException" error.
How can I give access and permission to that?

Comment: What are the access rights of that folder and the contained files?

Comment: drwxr-sr-x. 2 root elasticsearch    66 Oct 21 12:06 certs
-rw-------. 1 root elasticsearch 3451 Oct 21 12:06 elastic-certificates.p12

Comment: Yeah, `root` won't cut it, you need to set it to `elasticsearch`

Comment: Awesome, that's fantastic news!